PlasmoCSUI setting h-full cannot fill the parent node
PlasmoCSUI h-full not working
On twitter, I want to inject my own element (button) to the end of a list (a row of horizontal buttons), and I want to keep the same button height as them, but I found that my own element does not work with h-full and cannot fill the parent node. Does anyone know about this problem?
As shown below



import cssText from "data-text:~style.css"
import type { PlasmoCSConfig, PlasmoGetInlineAnchorList } from "plasmo"

export const getStyle = () => {
    const style = document.createElement("style")
    style.textContent = cssText.replaceAll(":root", ":host")
    return style
}
export const config: PlasmoCSConfig = {
    matches: ["*://*.x.com/*", "*://*.twitter.com/*"]
}

export const getInlineAnchorList: PlasmoGetInlineAnchorList = async () => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tablist"]:last-child')
    return Array.from(elements).map((el) => ({
        element: el,
        insertPosition: "beforeend"
    }))
}

const PlasmoCSUI = () => {
    return (
        <div className="my-auto flex items-center justify-center" style={{ height: 'var(--twitter-tab-height)' }}>
            <div className="my-auto w-9 h-full flex items-center justify-center ml-1 bg-red-500">
                tag
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlasmoCSUI


The framework uses shadow DOM, which will automatically generate two layers of div container nodes. I found the two node IDs in the web inspector, and then manually added height: 100% in style.css. As follows:
#plasmo-shadow-container {
    height: 100%;
}

#plasmo-inline {
    height: 100%;
}


